# Using Laravel 4, how do I mark a radio button as checked if a session key is a specified value?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, radio-button, laravel-blade

I have a multi-page form with two radio buttons with the same name attribute. When I select one and click the next step button, I save the value of that radio button into a session array with the form field name and chosen value. If the user comes back to the page, I want the previously chosen radiobutton to be checked.

This is what I came up with:

**View:** choose-listing-type.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
  <?php $checked_status = Session::get('listing_form_data.type') === 'property' ? true : false; ?>
  {{ Form::radio('type', 'property', $checked_status) }} Create Property Listing
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <?php $checked_status = Session::get('listing_form_data.type') === 'room' ? true : false; ?>
  {{ Form::radio('type', 'room', $checked_status) }} Create Room Listing
</div>
```

This works, but it seems sloppy. First off, I don't think the if statement that checks the session value should be in the view, and I would love to find a way to do this in blade.

Using Laravel 4, what is the best practice to mark a radiobutton as checked depending on the value of a specified session key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned you wanted to do it in the controller:

```
$type = Session::get('listing_form_data.type');
return View::make('view')->with('type', $type);
```

View:

```
{{ Form::radio('type', 'property', $type === 'property') }} Create Property Listing
{{ Form::radio('type', 'room', $type === 'room') }} Create Room Listing
```

---

Or even:

```
$type = Session::get('listing_form_data.type');
$isProperty = ($type === 'property');
$isRoom = ($type === 'room');
return View::make('view')->with(compact('isProperty', 'isRoom'));
```

View:

```
{{ Form::radio('type', 'property', $isProperty) }} Create Property Listing
{{ Form::radio('type', 'room', $isRoom) }} Create Room Listing
```

Comment: These are awesome! Would you agree that this sort of code belongs in the controller or am I being too picky?

Comment: No I would agree (the first version, the second is a bit extreme). The advantage is that view have to know where that type exactly is coming from. So if you would switch to a cookie you would change it in the controller. The view stays the same :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just put the conditional right inline with the Form helper, like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::radio('type', 'room', (Session::get('listing_form_data.type') === 'room') ? true : false) }} Create Room Listing
</div>
```

Personally I don't see anything wrong with checking a session setting from the view...

Comment: That's a good suggestion and one step in the right direction, but I was looking for some sort of solution that I can handle in the controller, which seems like a more appropriate solution.